# Meaning of $C^0$ close between knots

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants, contact-topology

Can any one tell the actual meaning (geometrically too) of '$C^0$ close' in the following theorem?

"Given any topological knot $K$ there is a Legendrian knot $C^0$ close to it".

When I read "Jhon B Etnyre's,  Legendrian and transversal knot" lecture notes I had this problem of understanding.

Thanks advance.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the context, I _think_ that $C^0$ is the name given to the Legendiran knot, and that $C^0$ is close to $K$.

Comment: @arthur, no I am Sure that it is not name. Because they never use that notation to give names to the Legendrian knots.

Comment: It probably means that there is another knot close to $K$ in the $C^0$-topology. He is viewing knots as their embeddings $S^1\to\mathbb R^3$, and he is saying that Legendrian knots are dense in the space of functions from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @Mariano, what do you mean by C^0 topology???

Comment: The topology of uniform convergence. (Usually *one* question mark is enough!)

Answer (score 2):

It means that for any $\epsilon >0$ and smooth knot $K$ (thought of as an embedding $K: S^1 \to S^3$),  there is a Legendrian knot $L:S^1 \to S^3$ so that $d(K(x),L(x))< \epsilon$ for all $x$ where $d$ is the usual distance function on $S^3$.